# Grails Error on GenerateViews: URL constraint can only be applied to a String property

Tags: grails

*Edit: resolved with Grails downgrade - see comments in accepted answer.

I'm new to grails and I'm trying to generate views for the following new domain (what I've done leading up to this point: created a new Grails Project, written this domain, and generated a controller for the domain):

```
package gormintro

class Employee {
    String first
    String last
    Date hireDate
    Integer salary
    String department

    static constraints = {
        first()
        last()
        hireDate()
        salary()
        department()
    }
}
```

Whenever I do so, I get the following error:

```
Error |
URL constraint can only be applied to a String property
```

Any ideas as to what could be happening here would be greatly appreciated!

Grails 2.3.6, GGTS 3.4.0.RELEASE

*Edit: Full error trace:

```
| Error Error executing script GenerateViews: URL constraint can only be applied to a String property
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: URL constraint can only be applied to a String property
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.isUrl(ConstrainedProperty.java:819)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1725)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1140)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3461)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at SimpleTemplateScript4.renderStringEditor(SimpleTemplateScript4.groovy:72)
    at SimpleTemplateScript4.this$4$renderStringEditor(SimpleTemplateScript4.groovy)
    at SimpleTemplateScript4$this$4$renderStringEditor.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at SimpleTemplateScript4.run(SimpleTemplateScript4.groovy:6)
    at groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine$SimpleTemplate$1.writeTo(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:165)
    at groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine$SimpleTemplate$1.toString(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator$_closure1.doCall(DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator.groovy:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1132)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1088)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at SimpleTemplateScript3.renderFieldForProperty(SimpleTemplateScript3.groovy:51)
    at SimpleTemplateScript3.renderFieldForProperty(SimpleTemplateScript3.groovy)
    at SimpleTemplateScript3.this$4$renderFieldForProperty(SimpleTemplateScript3.groovy)
    at SimpleTemplateScript3$this$4$renderFieldForProperty.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at SimpleTemplateScript3.run(SimpleTemplateScript3.groovy:29)
    at groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine$SimpleTemplate$1.writeTo(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.generate(AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.java:275)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.generateView(AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.generateView(AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.java:180)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.generateViews(AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.GrailsTemplateGenerator$generateViews.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at _GrailsGenerate_groovy.generateForDomainClass(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:731)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1132)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1088)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:731)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
    at GenerateViews$_run_closure1.doCall(GenerateViews:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:731)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:733)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:773)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:571)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:470)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
| Error Error executing script GenerateViews: URL constraint can only be applied to a String property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should either fill the constrains in, or remove them. In this form:

```
static constraints = {
    first()
    last()
    hireDate()
    salary()
    department()
}
```

they are meaningless and can also be harmless... (I've never tried to put them like that)

have them like so:

```
static constraints = {
    first( nullable:true )
    last( unique:true )
    hireDate()
    salary( min:1 )
    department()
}
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering - I had the constraints in their current form to override the default alphabetic ordering of the fields when using static scaffolding. I tried removing them like you said, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: are you seeing something else the the stacktrace? add `-verbose` to the `generate-views` commanf

Comment: I added the trace above - not sure what to look for I'm afraid!

Comment: this is weird... try removing the controller and run `generate-all`

Comment: Ok, I've tried this - It generates the _form.gsp, edit.gsp and index.gsp views, and the throws the same error. I guess the order of generate-all is views first then controllers, as no controller was generated with generate-all. Thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: Sorry for no answer. If it's not an issue for you, downgrade your project to Grails 2.2.x, as 2.3.x has ever had problems with something as I tried using it. Especially it's not fully supported by the newest GGTS. So I had no other choice than downgrading...

Comment: No problem thanks again for your help - I would up vote if I had the rep! I went with downgrading and found luck with grails-2.1.0 finally!

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a similar issue - while it was not perfect it was resolved by changing the variable names from "first" and "last" to "firstName" and "lastName".

First and last are methods on domain objects in grails.  I am new to grails but this certainly could be part of the issue.